# XPath: Fetch attribute of parent node only if all the child nodes have a specific value

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML document:

```
<root>
  <description name="testing1">
    <descriptionextension name="unda">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
    <descriptionextension name="koppu">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
    <descriptionextension name="valid">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
  </description>
  <description name="testing2">
    <descriptionextension name="valid">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
    <descriptionextension name="valid">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
    <descriptionextension name="valid">
      <type>test</type>
    </descriptionextension>
  </description>
</root>
```

This is the XPath query:

```
//description/descriptionextension[contains(@name,'valid')]/../@name
```

Is it possible to fetch the description name only if all child description extensions are 'valid'. Here I want to fetch only "testing2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution:

```
//description[empty(descriptionextension[@name != 'valid'])]/@name/string()
```

Here is another one (there are various others):

```
//description[not(descriptionextension/@name != 'valid')]/@name/string()
```

With XQuery, you can write:

```
for $d in //description
where every $de in $d/descriptionextension satisfies $de/@name = 'valid'
return $d/@name/string()
```

As you may have seen, a `description` will also be accepted if it has no `descriptionextension` child elements.

Comment: I like the `FLWOR` approach a lot, but - to be honest - it will return a `<description>` without any extension too. the approaches with `not()` and `empty()` (as well as `count()=0`) are an example how many ways exist. One might use `and` to enforce at least one `extension` together with one of the many ways to enforce *no other values*. Still a +1 from my side.

Comment: Thanks for your observation. I have moved the explanatory comment to the very end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look for all elements **without** any occurance **other** than "valid":

```
/root/description[count(descriptionextension[@name!="valid"])=0]/@name
```

Might be necessary to check what should happen if there is no extension at all...

Comment: I do +1 too, because of a clever way to do the trick. Mine is just what OP asked

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
string(//description[count(descriptionextension[@name="valid"]) = count(descriptionextension)]/@name)
```

### Output :

```
testing2
```

Comment: If there is a 4th extension other than "valid" this would fail. If there is a node with only valid extensions, but just two of them, it would fail too. I don't think, that you can rely on the number of elements...

Comment: Fixed snippet ;)

Comment: I'd prefer mine (negative thinking :-D) but this would work now... +1 from my side